# For what values of $ \alpha $ does the integral $ \int_0^\infty x^\alpha \left( 1- e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} \right) \, \mathrm d x $ converge?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

For what values of $ \alpha $, does this integral converge?
$$ \int_0^\infty x^\alpha \left( 1- e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} \right) \, \mathrm d x $$
I don't know what techniques to use to find out what is happening at $0$ or $\infty$. I tried with Riemann criterion but didn't find anything that could work. The problem is that I don't know which of  $x^\alpha$ or $1- e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$ go to $0$ or $\infty$ the fastest. I tried factorization by highest factor but its a bit weird with this.

Thank you very much if you can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know how to compute equivalents?

When $x\to 0$, $-1/\sqrt{x}$ tends to $-\infty$ and therefore the integrand is equivalent to $x^{\alpha}$.

Conversely, when $x \to\infty$, $-1/\sqrt{x}$ tends to $0$ and you're able to write that $1-e^{-1/\sqrt{x}}\sim 1/\sqrt{x}$, so that the integrand is equivalent to $x^{\alpha-1/2}$. You can then apply Riemann criterion (after justifying why you can use it here!)

Comment: I really dont know how to compute equivalent, are we using taylor expansion ?

Comment: It look like we are but why could whe juste use the first two character in the expansion. We are sayin that e^u=1+u if u tend to zero ?

Answer (score 3):

We have to study the asymptotic expansion of the integrand function $f(x)=x^a(1-e^{\frac{-1}{\sqrt x}})$ in a neighbourhood of $0$ and $+\infty$:
$$f(x)\sim\begin{cases}x^a &\text{for }x\in\mathcal U(0^+)\\x^{a-1/2} &\text{for }x\in\mathcal U(+\infty) \end{cases}$$
so you can now consider the integral $\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ as $\color{blue}{\int_0^{\delta}f(x)dx}+\color{red}{\int_{\delta}^{+\infty}f(x)dx}$, with $0<\delta<1$ and the two integrals are convergent iff $\color{blue}{a>-1}$ and $\color{red}{ a<-1/2}\implies$ the integral converges iff $a\in(-1,-1/2).$